# Is there a way to force that a method is tested?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I'd like to mark unit tested methods as tested in Java code, so that a compiler error occurs in case of a missing testing method. 
Is there a way to do that? I couldn't find a satisfying solution.

Comment: http://pitest.org/ perhaps, it won't meet your direct requirement but it does essentially test how good your tests are by introducing changes (mutations) e.g. an `if(true)` to `if(false)` if a test doesn't fail because of the mutation the mutation coverage is lowered etc.

Comment: What is your definition of "a method is tested"?  Called from some test code (could be part of setup / teardown rather than SUT exercise)?  Handled as the SUT in some test (the test could still be stupid, like assert(true))?  Tested somewhat sensibly (could find some bugs)?  Tested thoroughly (able to find all bugs one could plausibly think of)?

Comment: Instead of using something like SonarQube? Interesting. This would catch the problem earlier in the development stream. Still,  a TDD pair would have the benefit of a human confirming that the test is a legitimate test, more so that a compiler would.

Answer (score 0):

of course it's possible. you can write your own postprocessor that parses your code, finds marked method, runs tests, gets coverage results, compares them with marked methods and fails build if something is wrong.

but

1. it's a loooot of work
2. the benefit is very small. why? because what matter is not the coverage itself but quality of tests. you can even write a test generator that covers all / most of  your code automatically but it will have no value. good test checks for behaviour specific. and only devs know what behaviour is expected

the quality of test is usually covered by code reviews. at the pull request screen you can also display the stats of the pull request ie. code coverage etc. but i'm not sure if automating it further is worth the effort